# jquery Countdown Timer - reset on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, reset, countdowntimer

I have a countdown timer for logging out users (for admin site).
When a user press a key, it should resets the timer, but it's not working.

How should I reset the timer?

```js
$(function(){
 
 var perc = 50 // User will be logged out after (minutes)
 var count = perc * 60;
 
 // RESET TIMER
 
$(document).keypress(function(){
    var count = perc * 60;   // PROBLEM
 alert('keypress works');
});  
 
 
 //COUNTDOWN
 
 var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); 
 function timer() {
  count = count - 1;
  if (count == -1) {
   // LOGOUT //
   return;
  }

  var seconds = count % 60;
  var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);

  seconds %= 60;
  minutes %= 60;

  document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
  document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = minutes;
  document.getElementById("start_time").innerHTML = inactive;
  
 };

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu_countdown"><span id="minutes"></span> : <span id="seconds"></span></div>
```

Comment: FYI using setInterval and a counter is not accurate for tracking time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The var scopes it to the keypress closure

```
var count = perc * 60;   // PROBLEM
```

You need to remove the `var`.

```
$(document).keypress(function(){
    count = perc * 60;
});
```